# Detect hitbox - colission

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, game-physics

I am currently developing a kind of 2d game from a certain perspective (camera) and making it look like a 3d game.

The perspective never changes (turns).

Whatever. I have now reached the point of coding the hitboxes and the player is already able to recognize Colissions with other objects (Entitys).

Now I want to keep the player from running into other entities (hitboxes). My idea was to perform a colission detection as described below and then calculate the intersection so that I know on which side of the hitbox the player and the entity collide. Finally, I set the x or y speed of the player to 0, depending on where the overlap occurs.

I don't really know how to detect the Overlapping Axis / Axes, all I've found so far is that there is a Colission.

[image: img]

Colission:

```
function getColission(a, b) {
  return (a.x <= b.x+b.sizeX && a.x+a.sizeX >= b.x) &&
         (a.y <= b.y+b.sizeY && a.y+a.sizeY >= b.y) &&
         (a.z <= b.z+b.sizeX && a.z+a.sizeZ >= b.z);
}
```

Comment: Are the hitboxes always square/rectangular?

Comment: Oh yes they are sure rectangular - probably not square. @Chris

Comment: When a collision is detected you can call another function to see if shape A's right corner is farther right than shape B's left, A's top higher than B's bottom, etc. Not super graceful and might act strangely on edge-to-edge collisions, but it'd be a simple approach to locate the point of collision. This is assuming they're implemented similarly to your image.